# Interesting sum of $3\times 3$ determinants, using interchanging of rows and columns

Tags: matrices, determinant

To every $9$ digit number $\overline{abcdefghi}$ we associate the $3\times 3$ matrix:
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
         a &b &c \\
         d &e  &f\\
         g &h &i\\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Find the sum of determinants of all such matrices.

I am aware of the fact that I need to use the fact that interchanging two rows/columns changes the sign of the determinant, but I need some help on "pairing" the $9$ digit-numbers so that the determinants cancel out somehow.

I have to mention that I found this on a multiple-choice test, and the possible answers are :

a. a number of the form $9$$k$+$1$, with $k$ an integer

b. $999$

c. $-1$

d. $2022$

e. $other \,answer$

Comment: In fact,  interchanging two rows or columns *does* change the determinant.

Comment: Do you allow leading $0$'s in your numbers?

Comment: Whoops, my bad, I meant that they change sign, and the sum "doesn't change" as they cancel each other out. I edited it just now, thanks for the heads up!

Comment: No, a cannot be $0$, the numbers to which we associate these matrices have to be natural 9 digit numbers. Should have mentioned that.

Comment: Have you tried computing any explicit examples?  Have you tried a general calculation.

Comment: So the determinants of $\pmatrix{a & b & c\cr d & e & f\cr g & h & i\cr}$ and $\pmatrix{a & b & c\cr g & h & i\cr d & e & f\cr}$ add to $0$.  What does that tell you?

Comment: That most numbers, such as $123456789$, have a unique "counterpart", by interchanging the middle $3$ digits with the last $3$ digits, obtaining $123789456$.  So I thought that out of the $900$ million numbers, we can make $450$ million pairs which don't change the sum. But I have to rule out the numbers that don't "allow" a pair. Are the ones with the same last six digits the only ones, or is there something I am missing. If not, I think the answer should be $0$.

Comment: @DavidAnarch If switching rows produces a determinant of the same matrix, then it must be the case that the matrix has a repeated row, which means that its determinant is zero. Indeed, the answer overall should be zero

Comment: @DavidAnarch The corresponding "numbers that don't allow a pair" are those of the form $\overline{abcdefdef}$

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got a bit confused as $0$ wasn't really an answer, and I thought I miscounted or something.

Answer (score 0):

We can see that every arrangement $W$ to put the numbers in the Matrix has 3 other "Symmetric" arrangements :
$X$ , where we rotate it by $90^0$.
$Y$ , where we rotate it by $180^0$.
$Z$ , where we rotate it by $270^0$.
These 4 arrangements (when non-Zero) have Same magnitude but alternating Sign.
Hence , total must be $W+X+Y+Z=W-W+W-W$ which is $0$.

Alternately :
Every arrangement $A$ has a "Partner" arrangement $B$ where Column 1 is exchanged with Column 2.
When these 2 arrangements are not Identical , Determinants must have Same magnitude but alternating Sign.
Hence , total must be $A+B=A-A$ which is $0$.
When these 2 arrangements are Identical , Both Determinants must be 0.
Hence , total must be $A+A=0+0$ which is $0$.

Overall , taking all arrangements , total must be $0+0+0+.....0+0=0$

We can verify this with $2\times2$ Case with Numbers $1,2,3,4$.